# How can we get the different public IPs in many ranges as possible in Amazon Web Services EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have launched many EC2 instances. For each region, the public IPs are similar. Ex: 54.88.142.235 and 54.88.97.132. Those have same first 2 bytes (54.88) are same. I want those public IPs (in same region) must be allocated in different IP ranges (may be same the first byte). Can we control this?

Comment: Well, it might be possible to allocate and release until you get what you want after some time and cost. But why would that matter?

Comment: I'm testing an application (client/server). In that, the server will check the IPs of clients that need to different the IP range. But AWS allocated those IPs are same range (in same region). I need at least about 40 IPs like that. So the creation in different regions cannot resolve my problem. (we just have 8 regions only)

Comment: It seems like a reasonable question to ask why the IP address makes any difference at all, and whether you are attempting to solve the correct problem.

Comment: This is the feature of this app. It just requires that the first 2 bytes must different.

Comment: You can put / deploy your app inside a VPC and play with the IPs and IP ranges as you want. The only difference is that your app should also be inside the VPC and obviosuly you will be making use of the private IP.

Comment: Amazon EC2 Public IP Ranges - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot control this. If you request a public IP, you will be given one from the available pool. You will not be able to choose what that IP is.

Comment: Yes, I known. But can we control the range that IP belong to? As I known, AWS will use some IP ranges to allocate IPs for new instances. Ex, for region US East (Northern Virginia): 

72.44.32.0/19 (72.44.32.0 - 72.44.63.255) 

67.202.0.0/18 (67.202.0.0 - 67.202.63.255) 

75.101.128.0/17 (75.101.128.0 - 75.101.255.255) 

174.129.0.0/16 (174.129.0.0 - 174.129.255.255) ...

Comment: I think the closest you will get is between regions. Within a region all IP addresses are in the pool.

Comment: I'm trying by request/release Elastic IP (EIP, maximum 5 EIP/region) until those 5 EIPs reach my condition. So for 8 regions, I can got 40 different EIPs (then not release them  :) ). The others can use the random public IPs each time they start. Just spend some time :) .